# Saving a large graphics file

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to save a large heatmap that's roughly 20,000 x 20,000 tiles and 8.8 GB in size, and ggsave is taking a very long time to execute.

```
p <- large_plot %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_tile(aes(x, variable, fill = value), color = "white") +
  theme(axis.text = element_blank(),
              axis.title = element_blank(),
              axis.ticks = element_blank(),
              legend.title = element_blank()) +
  scale_fill_distiller(palette = "YlOrRd") +
  xlab(NULL) +
  ylab(NULL)

ggsave("plot.png", plot = p, width = 8, height = 7, units = "in", dpi = 300)
```

My question is: **what are some best programmatic practices to save very large graphics?** Are there some packages that accomplish this better than others? Are there ways to reduce processing time without sacrificing image quality?

Comment: `?geom_tile`: "geom_raster is a high performance special case for when all the tiles are the same size."

Comment: How big is matrix? can you give dimensions? Want to test this

Comment: @PoGibas - The matrix is roughly 20,000 x 20,000 values. Each value is a number 0-1. Now that I think about it, rounding the number to 1 decimal place might be a good way to bin the data into 10 parts, and reduce processing time. If you're successful, maybe a microbenchmark comparing different lengths of numbers would be interesting to see.

Comment: @Brian, that's a great comment! Unfortunately, my bottleneck isn't in creating and saving the plot, but in writing it to a PNG. It would be interesting to see how geom_raster and geom_tile compare against each other in a microbenchmark though now that you bring this up.

Comment: Consider that if each tile was rendered as a single pixel, you'd basically be generating a 40 megapixel image, ideal for printing as a full size poster. You may have better results saving as a PDF. My best suggestion is to look into binning columns and rows of your matrix and summarizing them to reduce the effective resolution.

Comment: @ Brian, I'll try PDF. Re: binning, I had the same idea, but the diagonal of this matrix is line of 1s, which is important to capture in the visualization.